# What is Imagick equivalent of following Imagemagick command?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

What is the Imagick equivalent of following Imagemagick command?

```
convert i.jpg -set colorspace RGB ( -clone 0 -fill black -colorize 100% ) ( -clone 0 colorspace gray -negate ) -compose blend -define compose:args=70,30 -composite o.jpg
```

I did the following Imagick commands, but it doesnt seem to be the same

```
$img = new Imagick("i.jpg");
$img->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
$clone1 = $img->clone();
$clone1->colorizeImage('black', 1.0);
$clone2 = $img->clone();
$clone2->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$clone2->negateImage(0);
$img->setOption('compose:args', '70x30');
$img->compositeImage($clone1, Imagick::COMPOSITE_BLEND, 0, 0);
$img->compositeImage($clone2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_BLEND, 0, 0);
$img->writeImage("o.jpg");
```

Where have I made mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, what you have is correct. Two minor issues will need to be addressed to match the CLI result.

#### First

Move the `setOption` line before reading any images in the `Imagick` object.

```php
$img = new Imagick();
$img->setOption('compose:args', '70x30');
$img->readImage("i.jpg");
// ...
```

#### Secound

Colorizing the black color to 100% usually results in a solid black image. For whatever reason,  there's no effect with [MagickColorizeImage](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagick_class.c#L7915) method. There's some work-arounds using `ImagickDraw` & background-color assignment listed within the comments on PHP.net's [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.colorizeimage.php). I'd recommend revisiting your first `$clone1` image.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Why do we need to perform setOption before reading the image?

Comment: I imagine this behavior may be related to PHP's copy-in-memory architecture, as opposed to the traditional pointer, reference, & allocations that you would expected in ImageMagick's (or any) standard library. In the end, it's a small little gotcha that exists in the user-space, not in the library or the API.

Comment: ok. Thanks! I have another question related to imagick at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248421/imagick-equivalent-of-this-imagemagick-command Can u kindly answer that too?

Comment: @emcconville can you please check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777570/how-to-use-auto-level-level-colors-command-argument-into-php-imagemagick