# Imagick Equivalent Of This Imagemagick Command?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to create a vignette effect, and I can get desired result through command line. But when I try it with Imagick, I'm not getting the desired result

```
convert i.jpg ( -size 150x150 radial-gradient:black-white -gravity center -crop 100x100+0+0 +repage ) -compose multiply -flatten o.jpg
```

I tried the following Imagick commands

```
$gra = new Imagick();
$gra->newPseudoImage(150, 150, "radial-gradient:black-white");
$gra->cropThumbnailImage(100, 100);
$gra->setImagePage(100, 100, 0, 0);
$img = new Imagick("i.jpg");
$img->compositeImage($gra, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0, 0);
$img->flattenImages();
$img->writeImage("o.jpg");
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not use [Imagick::vignetteImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.vignetteimage.php)? Seems like this is extra work, as your not doing any custom effects.

Comment: Well, vignetteImage doesnt seem to allow any customizations

Comment: There is a package dedicated to composing images with filters and layers. The package is called [pslayers](https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers) and we use it in production on a few of our apps.