# how to use -auto-level +level-colors command argument into PHP ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am converting the Image with a specific color and it is working fine with the `magick` command, below is my command,

`magick image.png -channel RGB -colorspace gray -auto-level +level-colors '#f48023',  result.png`

and it is working perfectly fine and now I am converting this command into `PHP` code but not sure about `-auto-level` and `+level-colors` argument. Here is my code,

```
$image = new Imagick('image.png');
$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);
$image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
$image->setImageType(Imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE);
$image->opaquePaintImage('','#f48023', 0, true);
$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

and the output looks not good at all,

[image]

here is my original Image

[image]

**EDIT(Updated code) **

```
$im = new Imagick();
$image = new Imagick('logo3.jpg');
list ($width, $height) = array_values ($image->getImageGeometry ());
$im->newImage(1, $height,new ImagickPixel('#f48023'));
$im->newImage(1, $height,new ImagickPixel('#FFF'));
$im->resetIterator();
$combine  =$im->appendImages(true);

$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);
$image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$image->contrastStretchImage(1,1,Imagick::CHANNEL_GRAY);
$image->clutImage($combine);
$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

and output of this code is below

[image]

logo3.jpg is here
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See autoLevelImage at https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.autolevelimage.php

I do not see any equivalent to +level-colors. But you can get a similar effect by creating a two pixel color map image, one pixel for each of two colors by appending the two 1-pixel images. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php

Then use clutImage to apply the colors from the color map image to the processed image. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.clutimage.php

**ADDITION:**

Here is what I mean using ImageMagick command line as an alternate to -auto-level and +level-colors. In the first command I use -auto-level and +level-colors. In the second command I use -contrast-stretch 0 (as equivalent to -auto-level) and a color map image with -clut as equivalent to +level-colors.

Input:

[image]

```
magick lorem_ipsum.png -colorspace gray -contrast-stretch 0 +level-colors '#f48023,' lorem_ipsum_recolor1.png
```

[image]

```
magick \( lorem_ipsum.png -colorspace gray -contrast-stretch 0 \) \
\( -size 1x1 xc:"#f48023" xc:white +append -filter cubic -resize 1024 \) \
-clut lorem_ipsum_recolor2.png
```

[image]

I do not see the need for -colorspace RGB, which would make the colors linear and darker. If you want to convert from some other colorspace, use -colorspace sRGB.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, do you have some example of it how to use it? I am new to `ImageMagick` :)

Comment: I do not normally use Imagick. But I know ImageMagick. I just looked at the documentation for Imagick and found the equivalent functions to what I would do in ImageMagick.

Comment: what you mean by " apply the colors from the color map image to the processed image" , can you please explain.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer. I show you the ImageMagick command line equivalent. In my original answer I suggest that you can use autoLevelImage (or contrastStretchImage) and clutImage. So I think you can now pull together the right PHP script from the commands I mentioned and the ImageMagick equivalent.

Comment: thanks, ok, let me try to convert in PHP script which I was facing the issue, as I was able to convert the Image with the command line but not with the PHP script,

Comment: why you choose 1*1 size Image for color? when I am setting the 1*1 size in PHP script output is not expected it should be, now I am passing the Image height 1 * $imageheight but it is not working for every Image, as I have dynamic Image form, and user can upload any type of Image, can you please help me with this?

Comment: Post your code. See my reply to your question on the ImageMagick forum also.

Comment: You did not resize the appended image before applying to your grayscale image. So try doing that.

Comment: I did resize but still Image quality is not good, In the comment, you mention about " contrast stretching it to full dynamic range" but in the PHP function is which is expecting https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.contraststretchimage.php `$black` and `$white` not sure what should I pass there and you passed `filter ` as `triangle`, what's the meaning of this?

Comment: I do not see resizeImage in any line of your code. Where is it?  Filter triangle does a linear spread of your orange and white colors. You can also try Filter cubic. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php#imagick.constants.filters. Replace your contrastStretchImage with autoLevelImage. That will be easier to use as you will not need any arguments. See the example at https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.autolevelimage.php

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you are truly gem :) now I am testing the multiple Images for some Images it's working good (mostly dark color Image) and for light Image it has problem (it has some light shead) for example https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/485-4852378_sample-logo-png-transparent-png.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218385/discussion-between-fmw42-and-keyur-shah).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in PHP Imagick, where I have added resizeImage to your combine image. You can try FILTER_TRIANGLE in place of FILTER_CUBIC and see which one you like better. I have also replace your contrastStretchImage with autoLevelImage.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$image = new Imagick('logo3.jpg');
list ($width, $height) = array_values ($image->getImageGeometry ());
$im->newImage(1, $height,new ImagickPixel('#f48023'));
$im->newImage(1, $height,new ImagickPixel('#FFF'));
$im->resetIterator();
$combine  =$im->appendImages(true);
$combine->resizeImage(1024,1,Imagick::FILTER_CUBIC,1)

$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);
$image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$image->autoLevelImage();
$image->clutImage($combine);
$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```